# How to turn off scrapy's ImagesPipeline to automatically create a full folder？

Tags: python, scrapy

When downloading images using scrapy's ImagesPipeline, I have set the save path, but I will still create a new full folder for me in the save path. I don't want it to create this full for me. How can I close it?
I set the path to the image storage in scrapy's settings.py.

```
IMAGES_STORE ='F:/test/exp'
```

When my crawler crawls the data, the image is saved in the path of ‘F:/test/exp/full’. I don't want my program to create this ‘full’ folder for me. But save it directly in the path I set

Comment: Could you provide more information? What happens and what you want to happen.

Comment: Sorry, I thought this question is very common, although I didn't get an answer to a similar question in the search. I have modified the issue. I hope you can help me, thank you.

Comment: Thanks for clearing it up, it's actually a good question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately `full` suffix to path is hardcoded in the pipeline:

```
# from scrapy 1.5.1 source code
def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None):
    ...
    image_guid = hashlib.sha1(to_bytes(url)).hexdigest() 
    return 'full/%s.jpg' % (image_guid)
```

However you can fix this by extending `ImagesPipeline` as your own, create file `myproject/pipelines.py`:

```
class RootImagesPipeline(ImagesPipeline):
    """changes /full/ path to root"""

    def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None):
    """This is the method used to determine file path"""
        path = super().file_path(request, response, info)
        return path.replace('full/', '')
```

and activate it instead of scrapy's pipeline in your `settings.py`:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'myproject.pipelines.RootImagesPipeline': 1000
}
```

Comment: @L.gen if you found that my answer is sufficient enough click the green checkmark to the left of it to mark this question answered so other people can find it more easily :)

Comment: Ok, thank you for your reminder. I am not familiar with Stack Overflow, thank you very much.